# Java multiple threads work on one field

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi I have the following piece of code:

```
public Item get(int id)
{
    Item i = null;
    for(Worker w : workers)
    {
        w.get(id, i); // Several threads start reading that item from data sources
    }
    while(i == null) // Loop until item is found
    {
        // this.pause(); there should be a pause but it's not a thread, so I can't do it.
    }
    return i;
}
```

I think there should be a better way, without that empty loop.

Something involving pausing the get function and resume only on notify by one of the workers.

Comment: Can can this empty loop possibly work?

Comment: Is that a question or a statement?

Comment: `i` will never be not null in your code. Your pass `null` to workers, not reference to `i`.

Comment: you are not even passing Item i reference to worker thread, then how will they update it

Comment: Yes, it's a typo, sorry for that. But I am passing a reference of i to the threads.

Comment: So when one of thread finds some item  - you should return it and don't bother about the rest?

Comment: Yes, as soon as one of the threads has it, return the value;

Comment: you are returning the reference, other threads can modify that reference

Comment: It doesn't matter, the value written by the workers is always the same for each call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) here. You create an instance of queue. And pass it to all workers. When worker finds item - it adds it to queue. And you just wait until queue is not empty:

```
public Item get(int id) {
    BlockingQueue<Item> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Item>(1);
    for(Worker w : workers) {
        w.get(id, queue); // Several threads start reading that item from data sources
    }
    return queue.take();
}
```

Use `queue.offer(foundItem);` in workers so they add item only when queue is empty.

Comment: OK, that is a great solution. It even handles the returns of the other threads correctly, i.e. ignoring them.

Comment: For exchange purpose you should use SynchronousQueue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html   Of course you should control other workers (not only first), because they makes overhead.